# How do I pass value to mysql query?

Tags: python, sql

I have flask app,I am trying to use inner join but i can not pass the value of that user_id. I am getting this error.

```
 mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
 near 'user_id = 1' at line 1
```

and this is my code:

```
user_id = msg_received["user_id"]
select_query1 = "SELECT * FROM user_table INNER JOIN coupon_table using user_id = %s"% user_id
```

please help me out.

Comment: Your main issue is with your SQL query syntax which is indeed invalid. There's no shortage of SQL tutorials and docs so I suggest you check MySQL's doc for the correct syntax. You have another issue, which is a security one, with the way you build your query, which can lead to a SQL injection attack. You can reds [this](https://bobby-tables.com/) for more on the topic and how to prevent it. In both cases, reading the existing doc should be enough to fix your issues.

Comment: Try this: select_query1 = "SELECT * FROM user_table INNER JOIN coupon_table using user_id = %s", user_id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this. Assuming that the relation between `user_table` and `coupon_table` is created on `user_id` key

```
SELECT *
FROM user_table INNER JOIN
     coupon_table 
     USING (user_id) 
WHERE user_id = %s"% user_id
```

EDIT:
This is **NOT** a best practice. Using string interpolation you are exposed to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: May I remind everyone here that using string interpolation to build SQL queries is **UNSAFE** ? https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing out. But the question is clear. He has a problem with the syntax and you should give an answer to that specifying that is not a best practice.